# Find a character in a comma delimited text file, and return the string it belongs to

Tags: python, scope, iterator, text-files

I have a bunch of comma-delimited text files that I would like to read in, find the location of a special character "X", and return "Z" in the same line where it belongs to, in string types. The text file looks like this:

```
"a1", "a2", "a3"
"b1", "b2", "b3"
"c1", "c2", "c3"
...
"X", "Y", "Z"
...
"n1", "n2", "n3"
```

The number of lines where "X" appears varies file by file. So I would like to write a function that can apply to all files, returning "Z" as a string.

I have tried the following code:

```
from itertools import islice
def _function():
    z = [0,0,0]
    f = open(file, 'r')
    num = sum(1 for line in f)
    for i in islice(f, 0, num):
        x = f.readline()
        y = x.find('X')
        if y == -1:
            pass
        else:
            z = f.readline().rstrip().split(',')
    return z[2]
```

However, when I run the code, I get 0 as my result, which means the code is not looping.
I also found that when I use `f = open(file)`, it only lasts for one line of code.

My current version is Python 3.7 on Anaconda. Thanks!

Comment: you should define variable `z` before your for loop

Comment: @Nihal So I defined ```z = [0,0,0]``` before the loop, and I got 0 as my result, which means the code is not looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1:**

For `y == -1` case you haven't provided any value for `z` (not anywhere else either for that matter), only in the `else` case.

So, what would be returned when getting the `z[2]` when `y == -1`?

In essense, you need to set a *placeholder* value for `z` for that case or before that. A better place for a placeholder would be to set it before the `for` loop so that you don't need to do the name binding on each iteration.

**Issue 2:**

You've already exhausted the file object *iterator* by counting lines:

```
num = sum(1 for line in f)
```

So when you do `f.readline()` next inside the loop it would always return an empty string.

An easy fix would be to `seek` back to the start of the file:

```
f.seek(0)
```

after num, and before entering the loop.

**But thats still not Pythonic**, the best way would be to iterate over the lines of the file (as file objects are iterators) using `for` loop, and do you work:

```
for line in f:
    y = line.find('X')
    ...
    ...
```

And of course, as `open` is a context manager, use that to automatically handle the proper `close`-ing of the file:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        # Do stuffs
```

*(Not going too much into your algorithm as that would be a question for code reviewing.)*

Comment: Thank you for your comments. So I defined ```z = [0,0,0]``` before the loop, and I got 0 as my result, which means the code is not looping. Could you please provide some insights on that?